# How to place a value to different arraylist?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, project

I am working on a restaurant simulation Project. However, I am stuck at the feedback part of my code. I took foods from the customer to an `ArrayList` and regarding this `ArrayList`, the program can ask question one by one for each food and take a rate value from customer. However I cannot place them into different ArrayLists. I want to do that because regarding the rates of the foods, the program should show the top rated food.

In short, I want to place rates to different Arrays.

```
public static ArrayList FeedBack(ArrayList<String> foods) {
    int foodtype;
    int rate;
    for (int i = 0; i < foods.size(); i++) {
        System.out.printf("%s", foods.get(i));
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("please rate that food out of 5");
        Scanner feedbackk = new Scanner(System.in);
        rate = feedbackk.nextInt();
        if ((foods.get(i)).equals("Fried Fries")) {

            RateOfFriedFries.add(rate);
            AllTheFoodRates.add(RateOfFriedFries);
        } else if (foods.get(i).equals("Meat Bal")) {
            RateOfMeatBall.add(rate);
            AllTheFoodRates.add(RateOfMeatBall);
        }
    }
    return AllTheFoodRates;
}
```

Comment: I didn't see any declaration of the ArrayList "AllTheFoodRates", "RateOfFriedFries" or "RateOfMeatBall".

Comment: these are at the beggining of the class as a public static variable . ı can add if you want

Comment: Then you don't need to return AllTheFoodRates,looks like problem is simple, now give a simple example what you want,

Comment: But I have to store the rates of foods for each food. AllTheFoodRates is a arraylist of array lists that stores RateOfMeatBall, RateOfFriedFries etc..

Comment: My question is how can I place the customer's rate into the different ArrayLists regarding the sort of food.

Comment: Don't make an ArrayList of ArrayList's... that just complicates things way more than needed....Make a Customer class.... in the customer class there will be ArrayList<Food>... the Food class will have a name and a List<Integer> of the different ratings....don't make the ArrayList's static... I can't find any reason for that if there are going to be multiple customers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it as follows:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Test
        List<String> foods=Arrays.asList("Fried Fries","Meat Bal");
        System.out.println(feedBack(foods));
    }
    public static List<ArrayList> feedBack(List<String> foods){
        int foodType;
        int rating;
        List<ArrayList> ratingOfAllFoods=new ArrayList<ArrayList>();
        List<Integer> ratingOfFriedFries=new ArrayList<Integer>();
        List<Integer> ratingOfMeatBall=new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for(int i=0;i<foods.size();i++)        {
            System.out.printf("%s%n",foods.get(i));
            System.out.print("Please rate that food out of 5: ");
            Scanner feedback=new Scanner(System.in);
            if(feedback.hasNextInt()) {
                rating=feedback.nextInt();
                if ("Fried Fries".equals(foods.get(i))) {
                    ratingOfFriedFries.add(rating);
                    ratingOfAllFoods.add((ArrayList) ratingOfFriedFries);
                }
                else if("Meat Bal".equals(foods.get(i))){
                    ratingOfMeatBall.add(rating);
                    ratingOfAllFoods.add((ArrayList) ratingOfMeatBall);
                }
              } else {
                  System.out.println("Invalid input");
              }
        }
        return ratingOfAllFoods;
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
Fried Fries
Please rate that food out of 5: 3
Meat Bal
Please rate that food out of 5: 4
[[3], [4]]
```

I also recommend you follow the naming convention of variables and function.

Comment: thank you Arvind Kumar Avinash it solved my problem.

Comment: Hey It worked for 2 foods but when ı want to add  some other foods it did not work what can I do?